# What's the difference between `Trustlessness` and `Decentralized`?

Tags: blockchain, decentralization, trust

Blockchain is known as a example of `trustless` and `decentralized` systems.

Some say that a `decentralized` system is an example of `trustless` systems.

What's the relationship between `trustlessness` and `decentralized`?

Answer (score 0):

*The relationship between trustfulness and decentralized is in how to work a system.*

You can think about banks. They have a system based on database and it has a single point of failure. Thus, a hacker can access to system and handle thousand of transaction at his  will. If a system has this disavantage, is centralized. For this two reasons, a centralized system **CANNOT** be consider decentralized and, at the same time, trustfullness.

Blockchain technology is consider like `trustfulness` and `decentralized` for the following reasons:

- It don't have a single point of failure but it based on nodes;
- Each transaction is public and everyone can read it;
- Every nodes have a copy of ledger that prevent eventually malicious transaction and give a updated version about ledger in a specific time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what's the difference between `trustfulness` and `decentralized`? Do they basically mean the same thing?